# Django serializers: Why source argument in does not work?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following Serializer in my Django project:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    CheckList1 = serializers.CharField(source='source_field', default="pass")
```

I use it for data validation, like this:

```
input_serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
input_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

The source argument seems to be not working. I pass there the request data that looks like this:

```
request.data = {
   source_field = "Failed"
}
```

when I print input_serializer.data the value of *CheckList1* is *pass*. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`.validated_data`** attribute.

Hope this example helps you to do so,

```
class Foo(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = serializers.CharField(source='bar')


input_data = {
    'foo': 'this data is for foo',
    'bar': 'this data is for bar'
}

f = Foo(data=input_data)
f.is_valid(True)

print('f.validated_data', dict(f.validated_data))
# f.validated_data {'bar': 'this data is for foo'}
print('f.data', f.data)
# f.data {'foo': 'this data is for foo'}
```

Comment: Its not working if we add required as True...  `serializers.CharField(source='bar', required=True)`. Any way to include required as well...??